# A Tribute to Countdown

Tags: calculation-puzzle, formation-of-numbers

Leave empty or put a multiplier, divider, adder or subtractor in the boxes:

[image: question]

For example:

[image: example]

Comment: The arrow in the second picture doesn't seem to change anything?

Comment: this is also from oyun.tzv.org.tr... without any reference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

2648:

> 1-2*3*4+5*67*8-9

1942:

> 1*2/3+4*56*78/9

2899:

> 1+23/4*567*8/9

2869:

> 123*4*5/6*7+8-9

1278:

> 1+2/3*45*6*7+8+9